# Can I use sqllite with a mySQL backup file?

Tags: c#, mysql, sqlite, offline, system.data.sqlite

If i wanted to use a mySQL database offline, could i download it from a server and `SELECT` from it when i am offline? That way I could use the version on the server when online, and use the local copy when offline.

i want to do something like this:

```
sql_con = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=MySQLDB.sql")
```

Comment: You can export from MySQL in compatible SQL dialect and re-import that dump into SQLite, but why aren't you just setup a local MySQL-server?

Comment: it's for a product i need to ship. I don't think I can embed a local server into an application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use your MySQL database offline, it would be much easier for you to run a second instance of the MySQL server software on your own computer.  Replicate the server database on your computer and then, when you want to use the local copy, attach to the local MySQL instance.

Comment: is there a way i could embed MySQL server software into an application so it doens't look like its running?

Comment: No, as far as I know MySQL is strictly server software.  However, this page: http://www.mysql.com/oem/ talks about MySQL as "embedded" software.  I *think* they just mean silently installing the server, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: thanks so much for your help larry, i'll try and go a different path.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL and SQLite are two completely different databases with wildly different file formats. So straight file reuse is not an option. You can, however, export the database from MySQL in SQLite-friendly format (like CSV, or straight-out SQL), and import that into SQLite. There will be some coding involved, most likely.